# FM to simulate Delivery without Reference Sales Order

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp, function-module

Is there other known FM that can be used to simulate deliveries aside from FM `SD_SCD_SIMULATE_DELIVERIES`? This FM `SD_SCD_SIMULATE_DELIVERIES` needs `SALES_ORDER` as mandatory importing parameter and I don't have `SALES_ORDER`. Please advise.

Thanks!

-CZa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating deliveries without reference to a sales order, you can use BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CREATENOREF.

**Parameter | Opt. | Description**

**Import**

- SHIP_POINT | | Shipping point
- DLV_TYPE | | Delivery type
- SALESORG | | Sales organization
- DISTR_CHAN | | Distribution channel
- DIVISION | | Division
- SHIP_TO | | Ship-to party
- DATE_USAGE | X | Use of dates in DATES
- DEBUG_FLG | X | Forces termination (ALE analysis)

**Export**

- DELIVERY | X | First generated delivery
- NUM_DELIVERIES | X | Number of generated deliveries

**Parameter | Opt | Direction | Description**

**Tables**

- DATES | |  Import | Delivery date
- DLV_ITEMS | | Import | Delivery items to be created without reference
- SERIAL_NUMBERS | X | Import | Serial numbers
- EXTENSION_IN | X | Import | Additional input data
- DELIVERIES | X | Export | Generated deliveries
- CREATED_ITEMS | X | Export | Generated delivery items
- EXTENSION_OUT | X | Export | Additional output data
- RETURN | X | Export | Error log

I'm not sure if there is such a BAPI that only simulates an outbound delivery. A workaround you could use is to call this BAPI without calling BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT, and then do a ROLLBACK WORK in case there was already a COMMIT.

Comment: Yup! Thanks @Marco. I have also ran through the documentation of this FM and it is good.